# Cron jobs using Whenever with VM, Docker & Dokku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, docker, whenever, dokku

I have a Ruby on Rails app in a Docker container on Ubuntu 14.04.  I set up my deployments using Dokku but I'm unsure how to get my cron jobs working correctly.

Currently I'm using the [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever) which allows me to do something simple like:

```
every 5.minutes do
  runner 'MyModel.run_something'
end
```

The problem is I think that every time I deploy using `git push dokku master` it resets the container and setting it back to it's default thus removing all my cron schedules.

So then I thought maybe the cron scheduling needs to be outside the container and at the VM level instead.

I currently don't see any cron jobs running no matter what I do.  Here's what happens when I run `crontab -l` when ssh'd:

```
root@dashboard:~# crontab -l
no crontab for root
```

I'm pretty new to container virtualization so I apologize if I've skipped over a critical part of this but I'm a stumped.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Took me forever to work this one out - ended up call the rails command instead via crontabs.  I've also got a rails app uploaded on dokku with ubuntu on the digital ocean server.  Trying to get the Whenever gem to work... it just doesn't.  `whenever -i` doesn't work.

Whenever doesn't actually create any new crontabs for the dokku environment.  It's good for figuring out the Cron syntax though!

So this is how I got scheduled tasks to work in dokku:

1. Manually create your own crontab via `sudo crontab -e` which will open it up in vi/vim

You can use `sudo crontab -r` to remove it, or `sudo crontab -l` to view current crontabs

2. Add the following code to the new crontab

The below code will execute every 1 minute.

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
* * * * * /bin/bash -c 'dokku run appname rails r MyModel.run_something'
```

Make your environmental variables are equivalent to ones you have in the `env` command

3. `grep CRON /var/log/syslog` to see the output log for trouble shooting.  You may have to install postfix via `sudo apt-get install postfix` in order for Cron to send mail notification of errors otherwise you may get `“(CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)”` error from the syslog.
4. `cat /var/mail/root` to view the mail received from Cron - stating errors if a cronjob fails to work.

Hopefully that's helpful. That's what got me through at least!

Comment: Good workaround but I believe it's really hard to maintain and whenever is out of question, I thought of using `run` too and I'm trying to find a more robust alternative, good call though.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever probably isn't working because the cron daemon isn't running in your Docker/Dokku container. Docker will [only run the processes it is told to](http://phusion.github.io/baseimage-docker/), using either a `CMD` or `RUN` directive or in a script executed by one of those directives.

The Dokku guys have explicitly said  that cron [is not supported in Dokku](https://github.com/progrium/dokku/issues/450), though without saying why. A quick search for `cron` in the [Dokku](https://github.com/progrium/dokku), [Buildstep](https://github.com/progrium/buildstep) and Dokku [base image](https://github.com/progrium/cedarish) repos brings up no results, so it seems to be the case that Dokku never starts a cron service when building/running an app.

The solutions they suggest are to either set up the cron job on the host machine (as you've already figured out), use a [web_based scheduling service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webcron), or try Heroku's [Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler).

Comment: Thanks Nick, there's some great information shared here.

Comment: Note: while dokku currently *does not* manage cron, we *do* have official documentation on how to use dokku in conjunction with cron [here](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/deployment/one-off-processes/).